# Naming convention to use when converting from database to java variables

Tags: java, database, naming-conventions

I'm currently working on a project where I'm converting database info to java objects, and I was curious has to how I should represent/name the objects and variables on the java side.

For example, if I'm converting a table named Dog containing info about dogs such as: 
Column: `BREED_C, NAME_C, OWNER_C, DOGID_D, HAS_RABIES_I` and so on into a java object called Dog with corresponding variables, should I follow a java naming convention such as `BreedC` or use `Breed_C` or even `BREED_C` so there's as little discrepancy between the two systems?

Comment: I would always recommend the Java convention

Comment: What does the "C" in `BREED_C` indicate?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If working in Java, use Java naming conventions.

It sounds like your code should be responsible for abstracting the database layer away from the rest of the application anyway so there is no reason to expose the database representation by naming the Java variables with the exact same name as the database columns.

Comment: Would there ever be a case where I would want to use a different convention?

Comment: None that I've come across in 12 years of professional Java development.

Comment: So I'm halfway into the project that I had posted this question for. XStream converts java objects to xml and back again, and uses the variable names for the xml node names. Thus if I were to use standard java naming conventions, I would have to alias all the xml node names back into what the schema is requiring (Formatted like ThisTimeStamp instead of thisTimeStamp) etc. Would this be considered an appropriate place to use a different naming convention?

Comment: I would vote no.  I've not used XStream, but it looks like aliasing is a simple annotation that you can place on the fields.

Comment: Thanks, I'll think about that

Answer (score 1):

I guess C, D and I are the types of the columns, which are not necessary in Java, because you have types for fields and getters/setters.

This begin said, use the Java lowerCamelCase convention whenever possible.

All well known Java database abstraction projects (JPA) go this way.

Answer (score 1):

Acording to the *Code Conventions for the Java Programming Language*, says for Class's names

> Class names should be nouns, in mixed case with the ﬁrst letter of
>   each internal word capitalized. Try to keep your class names simple
>   and descriptive. Use whole words—avoid acronyms and abbreviations
>   (unless the abbreviation is much more widely used than the long form,
>   such as URL or HTML).

And the variables's names

> Except for variables, all instance, class,   and class constants are
>   in mixed case with a lowercase ﬁrst letter. Internal words start with
>   capital letters.

You can use this methods for convert `database` names to `Java` names.

```
public static String toJavaFieldName(String name) { // "MY_COLUMN"
    String name0 = name.replace("_", " "); // to "MY COLUMN"
    name0 = WordUtils.capitalizeFully(name0); // to "My Column"
    name0 = name0.replace(" ", ""); // to "MyColumn"
    name0 = WordUtils.uncapitalize(name0); // to "myColumn"
    return name0;
}

public static String toJavaClassName(String name) { // "MY_TABLE"
    String name0 = name.replace("_", " "); // to "MY TABLE"
    name0 = WordUtils.capitalizeFully(name0); // to "My Table"
    name0 = name0.replace(" ", ""); // to "MyTable"
    return name0;
}
```

This methods using [Apache Commons Lang](http://commons.apache.org/lang/).

Answer (score 0):

Better is use Java convention, so breedC should be your choice. If you're using JPA, adding `@Column(name="BREED_C")` over the breedC field can make the trick to join the two systems.

**EDIT:** Using your case as an example:

```
@Table(name="DOG")
public class Dog {
    @Column(name="BREED_C")
    private String breedC;
}
```

If the field name matches the column name, you don't need those annotiations, but if they're different, as your case, you need to put them. But only if you're using something like JPA.

Comment: Are you saying to label my variables with javadoc containing the db column names?

Comment: If you're using Hibernate or JPA, you should indicate which field corresponds to which column, so you should use annotations. I'll edit the answer with a more complete example